# Simple dispatcher implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I need a simple dispatcher implementation(invoke methods on one thread from many threads) 
once you dispatch method curent thread should wait for results, so I'm thinking about something like this:

```
public class Dispatcher
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Tuple<Delegate, object[]>> runQueue = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<Delegate, object[]>>();
    private readonly BlockingCollection<object> resultQueue = new BlockingCollection<object>();
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly Task task;
    public Dispatcher()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (source)
            using (runQueue)
            using (resultQueue)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Dispatcher started with thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                while (!source.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var run = runQueue.Take(source.Token);
                    resultQueue.Add(run.Item1.DynamicInvoke(run.Item2));
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Dispatcher ended");
            }
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        source.Cancel();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public object Invoke(Delegate @delegate, params object[] @params)
    {
        runQueue.Add(new Tuple<Delegate, object[]>(@delegate, @params));
        return resultQueue.Take(source.Token);
    }
}
```

I had test it with such code and it seems too work well ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<int, int, int> func = (sleep, i) =>
        {
            CC.WriteLine(i, "\tTask {0} will sleep for {1}, thread {2}", i, sleep, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(sleep);
            CC.WriteLine(i, "\tTask {0} woke up", i, sleep);
            return i; //return task number
        };
        var rnd = new Random();
        var disp = new Dispatcher();
        {
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i =>
                            Task.Run(() =>
                            {
                                CC.WriteLine(i, "Task {0} started, thread {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                                CC.WriteLine(i, "Task {0} ended with {1}", i, disp.Invoke(func, rnd.Next(3, 15) * 100, i));
                            })).ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            disp.Stop();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    static class CC
    {
        public static readonly List<ConsoleColor> COLORS = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Cast<ConsoleColor>().ToList();
        static CC()
        {
            COLORS.RemoveAt(0);
            COLORS.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        public static void WriteLine(int colorIndex, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            lock (COLORS)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = COLORS[colorIndex];
                Console.WriteLine(format, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is a BlockingCollection a good choice? 
Or maybe it can be done with something simpler? (SlimSemaphore)?

Comment: Why do you need that Dispatcher class. Why not simply use a Task?

Comment: It because for some reasons(using thrid party native API) i need to **invoke some code on one given thread** from multiple threads **and wait for the resutls** ... and AFAIK there is no way for doing this with just a task...

Comment: ... and yes, I'm aware of `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` but it is really bloated

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Because the task within the Dispatcher is a long running task, you should use the option `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. Otherwise the operation blocks a thread-pool thread that is usually used for short operations. Alternatively you could also use a `Thread`.
- Instead of using the blocking collection for returning the result, you could use a `TaskCompletionSource`. That would change the return value of the method `Invoke` to `Task<T>`. Therfore the calling code could use the async/await-pattern.
- Consider to throw an exception if the `Dispatcher` was stopped and `Invoke` is called. Otherwise the call blocks forever, right?

Comment: googling for TaskCreationOptions gives me [similar question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43000/a-taskscheduler-that-always-run-tasks-in-a-specific-thread) what do you think about it?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @JanDotNet for your help ... googling around your hints gives me what I really need SingleThreadTaskScheduler based on [StaTaskScheduler](https://github.com/bevacqua/Swarm/blob/master/Swarm.Common.Threading/TaskSchedulers/StaTaskScheduler.cs) from [Swarm](https://github.com/bevacqua/Swarm)

```
public sealed class SingleThreadTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
{
    private BlockingCollection<Task> _tasks;
    private readonly Thread _thread;

    public SingleThreadTaskScheduler()
    {
        // Initialize the tasks collection
        _tasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
        _thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Continually get the next task and try to execute it.
            // This will continue until the scheduler is disposed and no more tasks remain.
            foreach (var t in _tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                TryExecuteTask(t);
            }
        });
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Name = "SingleThreadTaskScheduler-"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _thread.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>Queues a Task to be executed by this scheduler.</summary>
    /// <param name="task">The task to be executed.</param>
    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        // Push it into the blocking collection of tasks
        _tasks.Add(task);
    }

    /// <summary>Provides a list of the scheduled tasks for the debugger to consume.</summary>
    /// <returns>An enumerable of all tasks currently scheduled.</returns>
    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        // Serialize the contents of the blocking collection of tasks for the debugger
        return _tasks.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>Determines whether a Task may be inlined.</summary>
    /// <param name="task">The task to be executed.</param>
    /// <param name="taskWasPreviouslyQueued">Whether the task was previously queued.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the task was successfully inlined; otherwise, false.</returns>
    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == _thread.ManagedThreadId && TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    /// <summary>Gets the maximum concurrency level supported by this scheduler.</summary>
    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up the scheduler by indicating that no more tasks will be queued.
    /// This method blocks until all threads successfully shutdown.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_tasks != null)
        {
            // Indicate that no new tasks will be coming in
            _tasks.CompleteAdding();
            // Wait for all threads to finish processing tasks
            _thread.Join();
            // Cleanup
            _tasks.Dispose();
            _tasks = null;
        }
    }
```

and usage

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Func<int, int, int> func = (sleep, i) =>
        {
            CC.WriteLine(i, "\tTask {0} will sleep for {1}, thread {2}", i, sleep, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(sleep);
            CC.WriteLine(i, "\tTask {0} woke up", i, sleep);
            if (i == 5)
                throw new Exception("Exception test!");
            return i; //return task number
        };
        using (var scheduler = new SingleThreadTaskScheduler())
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i =>
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    CC.WriteLine(i, "Task {0} started, thread {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    object r = null;
                    try
                    {
                        r = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(rnd.Next(3, 15) * 100, i), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        CC.WriteLine(i, "Task {0} ended with {1}", i, r);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        CC.WriteLine(i, "Task {0} exception: {1}", i, ex);
                    }

                })).ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    static class CC
    {
        public static readonly List<ConsoleColor> COLORS = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Cast<ConsoleColor>().ToList();
        static CC()
        {
            COLORS.RemoveAt(0);
            COLORS.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        public static void WriteLine(int colorIndex, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            lock (COLORS)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = COLORS[colorIndex];
                Console.WriteLine(format, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to solve your problem also. However, it is a little bit complicated to use... I am not sure if I would prefer that solution or your Dispatcher with a TaskCompletionSource...

Comment: why *it is a little bit complicated to use* ?`r = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(100, 1), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);` is pretty simple ... (with creating static TaskFactory usage would looks like `var r = await TFactory.StartNew(() => func(100, 1));`) ... unfortunatly I can't use it in my code ...

Comment: yes, that is simple... but you have to create the `SingleThreadTaskScheduler` first.. On the other side, the dispatcher have to be created first in the same way so maybe there is not difference ;) Why couldn't you use it in your code?

Comment: @JanDotNet look at 2nd revision of my question it is all about using "by ref" in lambdas

Comment: Ok.... Using native methods that way looks adventurous. Maybe you could wrap that method calls within your own class!?